# OSError: Invalid enum backend type 64 (Paddleseg, Paddlepaddle)

Tags: python, paddle-paddle

**Hardware**
CPU noavx

**Environment Information**
platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python: 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Paddle compiled with cuda: False
GCC: gcc (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0
PaddleSeg: 2.8.0
PaddlePaddle: 2.4.2
OpenCV: 4.5.5

**Library**
Paddlepaddle version: 2.4.1 (Compiled noavx *.whl)

I did all steps by [these instructions](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleSeg/blob/release/2.8/Matting/docs/quick_start_en.md)

When I run:

```
python tools/predict.py --config configs/ppmattingv2/ppmattingv2-stdc1-human_512.yml --model_path pretrained_models/ppmattingv2-stdc1-human_512.pdparams --image_path demo/human.jpg --save_dir output/results --device CPU
```

I get this error:

```
python tools/predict.py --config configs/ppmattingv2/ppmattingv2-stdc1-human_512.yml --model_path pretrained_models/ppmattingv2-stdc1-human_512.pdparams --image_path demo/human.jpg --save_dir output/results --fg_estimate True --device CPU
D:\paddleseg_python3.8.0\WPy64-3.8.0.0\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:121: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API
  warnings.warn("pkg_resources is deprecated as an API", DeprecationWarning)
D:\paddleseg_python3.8.0\WPy64-3.8.0.0\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2870: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('mpl_toolkits')`.
Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
  declare_namespace(pkg)
D:\paddleseg_python3.8.0\WPy64-3.8.0.0\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2870: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('google')`.
Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
  declare_namespace(pkg)
D:\paddleseg_python3.8.0\WPy64-3.8.0.0\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2870: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('zope')`.
Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
  declare_namespace(pkg)
D:\paddleseg_python3.8.0\PaddleSeg\Matting\tools\..\ppmatting\metrics\metric.py:23: DeprecationWarning: Please use `convolve` from the `scipy.ndimage` namespace, the `scipy.ndimage.filters` namespace is deprecated.
  from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve
2023-05-01 20:09:41 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------
2023-05-01 20:09:41 [INFO]
---------------Config Information---------------
batch_size: 16
iters: 100000
train_dataset:
  dataset_root: data/PPM-100
  mode: train
  train_file: train.txt
  transforms:
  - type: LoadImages
  - max_short: 512
    type: LimitShort
  - crop_size:
    - 512
    - 512
    type: RandomCrop
  - target_size:
    - 512
    - 512
    type: Padding
  - type: RandomDistort
  - prob: 0.1
    type: RandomBlur
  - prob: 0.2
    type: RandomSharpen
  - prob: 0.5
    type: RandomNoise
  - prob: 0.2
    type: RandomReJpeg
  - type: RandomHorizontalFlip
  - type: Normalize
  type: MattingDataset
val_dataset:
  dataset_root: data/PPM-100
  get_trimap: false
  mode: val
  transforms:
  - type: LoadImages
  - max_short: 512
    type: LimitShort
  - mult_int: 32
    type: ResizeToIntMult
  - type: Normalize
  type: MattingDataset
  val_file: val.txt
optimizer:
  momentum: 0.9
  type: sgd
  weight_decay: 0.0005
lr_scheduler:
  end_lr: 0
  learning_rate: 0.01
  power: 0.9
  type: PolynomialDecay
  warmup_iters: 1000
  warmup_start_lr: 1.0e-05
model:
  backbone:
    pretrained: https://bj.bcebos.com/paddleseg/dygraph/PP_STDCNet1.tar.gz
    type: STDC1
  decoder_channels:
  - 128
  - 96
  - 64
  - 32
  - 16
  dpp_merge_type: add
  dpp_output_channel: 256
  head_channel: 8
  type: PPMattingV2
------------------------------------------------

2023-05-01 20:09:41 [INFO]      Set device: cpu
2023-05-01 20:09:41 [INFO]      Use the following config to build model
model:
  backbone:
    pretrained: https://bj.bcebos.com/paddleseg/dygraph/PP_STDCNet1.tar.gz
    type: STDC1
  decoder_channels:
  - 128
  - 96
  - 64
  - 32
  - 16
  dpp_merge_type: add
  dpp_output_channel: 256
  head_channel: 8
  type: PPMattingV2
2023-05-01 20:09:42 [INFO]      Loading pretrained model from https://bj.bcebos.com/paddleseg/dygraph/PP_STDCNet1.tar.gz
2023-05-01 20:09:42 [INFO]      There are 145/145 variables loaded into STDCNet.
2023-05-01 20:09:43 [INFO]      Number of predict images = 1
2023-05-01 20:09:43 [INFO]      Loading pretrained model from pretrained_models/ppmattingv2-stdc1-human_512.pdparams
2023-05-01 20:09:43 [INFO]      There are 485/485 variables loaded into PPMattingV2.
2023-05-01 20:09:43 [INFO]      Start to predict...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/predict.py", line 114, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "tools/predict.py", line 101, in main
    predict(
  File "D:\paddleseg_python3.8.0\PaddleSeg\Matting\tools\..\ppmatting\core\predict.py", line 158, in predict
    data = preprocess(img=im_path, transforms=transforms, trimap=trimap)
  File "D:\paddleseg_python3.8.0\PaddleSeg\Matting\tools\..\ppmatting\core\predict.py", line 105, in preprocess
    data['img'] = data['img'].unsqueeze(0)
  File "D:\paddleseg_python3.8.0\WPy64-3.8.0.0\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\paddle\tensor\manipulation.py", line 2595, in unsqueeze
    return _C_ops.unsqueeze(input, axes)
OSError: Invalid enum backend type `64`.
  [C:\home\workspace\Paddle\paddle/phi/common/backend.h:140]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.